# xml parsing with Sax Parser in glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: java, xml, glassfish, sax

I have an xml file that i use to store an application configuration with the option of being updated offline.
Now when my web application starts, the SAXParser is loaded fine. The problem arises when i try to reload the xml file. I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1411)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(NewInstance.java:49)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:187)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:150)
```

what would be the problem?
I work with jdk 6u26
netbeans 6.9.1 and glassfish3.1

Comment: Have you seen [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225088/problem-with-netbeans-web-service-client-when-xercesimpl-jar-is-on-classpath)

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause in Guava map.put](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912594/illegalstateexception-cant-overwrite-cause-in-guava-map-put)

Comment: @maress did you ever come around to solve this?

Comment: @PaulSweatte Thats not a good dupe candidate for this question.